# When does MST-based approximation algorithm not return optimal solution to TSP?

Tags: algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman, minimum-spanning-tree

Given a complete, weighted graph G,such that its edge weights satisfy the triangle inequality but the MST-based approximation algorithm for TSP does not find an optimal solution.

Comment: The [relevant wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm#Example) has an example

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not a question. Did you mean *give* a complete... ?

The MST approximation rarely gives the optimal solution. It should be pretty easy to come up with an example.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Did you mean to leave a comment?

Comment: I meant it as an answer to the title. When does MST not return the optimal solution? Answer: Almost always.

Comment: This is a question from my textbook. Algorithm Designs and Applications - Michael T. Goodrich. It's a valid question.

Comment: That's fine, it's just that there is a typo and I couldn't understand whether you meant "*Give* a graph such that..." or something like "Given a graph such that MST is not optimal, prove that ..." but the "prove that" part was missing. I think it's the former, which is what I assumed.